# Elegant PHP variables

Tags: php

An empty $movies array given to the for loop will yield a warning. Checking for null avoids this. Not that i see this as ugly or messy code i'd just like to know if there are any more elegant ways of handling these instances.

```
function get_db_movies($db_handle) {
    $query = "SELECT title FROM movies";
    $result = $db_handle->query($query);
    $movies = null;
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        $movie = new Movie($row['title'], $db_handle);
        $movies[] = $movie;
    }
    return $movies;
}

$movies = get_db_movies($db_handle);

foreach($movies as $movie) {
    $imdbCrawl = new imdbCrawler($movie);
    if($imdbCrawl->verifyMatch() && $imdbCrawl->isMovieFound()) {
        $imdbCrawl->getRating();
        $imdbCrawl->getPlot();
        $movie->syncDatabase();
    } else {
        echo "Movie crawl failed: " . $movie->getTitle();
    }
}
```

Comment: @Salman A Elegancy is not a word :)

Comment: I personally don't find very elegant the way you're passing `$db_handle` in the Movie constructor. I would pass it in `syncDatabase()` and other methods that need it. But, not seeing the rest of your code it's hard to tell.

Comment: the definition of *elegant code* is subjective -- see [what is elegant code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/563036/what-is-elegant-code)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Initialize $movies to an empty array instead of null:

```
$movies = array();
```

Answer (score 3):

You may initialize an array before use to avoid the warning:

```
$movies = array();
```